# Customize DjangoRestFramework Browsable API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.11.0 and I want to use the BrowsableAPIRenderer with a customized template for rendering the details of an instance. I only want to override the rendering of the dict/json, marked red in the image below, and I want to keep all the rest.

By overwriting `restframework/api.html` I only managed to change the title, heading and some fields, but I did not find a way to render the details of an instance e.g. in a table. Is there a way to do this?

**Clarification**: I have models with large dictionaries that I want to display prettier than just as inline strings. I thin that when I find out how to customize the (already beautiful) Django RestFramework BrowsableAPI, I will also be able to solve my problem.

(Look at my Update 2 in case you want to solve a similar problem.)

[image: Screenshot]

---

### Update 1

This is where I got with [Bedilbeks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60599661) (up to the first update).

I don't want to change all views, so I'm not registering the renderer globally.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
         # 'users.renderers.CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

Instead I am setting the `renderer_classes` for my `UserViewSet` and use my `CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer` here.

```
class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer, CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer]
```

I need to override the `api.html` template, but I do not want this change to apply everywhere, so I am dynamically choosing the the template in the renderer. By default the `BrowsableAPIRenderer` has a `template = "rest_framework/api.html"` property, but I need logic so I'm using the `@property` decorator to do the following:

- check if we are in `detail` view
- check GET parameters

If we are in detail view and a `"table"` parameter is present, return my template, else return the default.

```
class CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):
    @property
    def template(self):
        view = self.renderer_context.get("view", {})
        table = "table" in view.request.query_params
        if view and hasattr(view, "detail") and view.detail and table:
            return "users/api.html"  # custom template
        else:
            return "rest_framework/api.html"  # default

    def get_default_renderer(self, view):
        table = "table" in view.request.query_params
        if hasattr(view, "detail") and view.detail and table:
            return TableHtmlRenderer()

        return super().get_default_renderer(view)
```

The crucial section of `api.html` looks like this (around line 123).

```
...
{% block style %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/api.css" %}"/>
{% endblock %}

<!-- HERE IS THE ACTUAL CONTENT -->
</span></pre><div class="prettyprint" style="overflow: auto;">{{ content|urlize_quoted_links }}</div>
            </div>
...
```

I'm actually not doing this for the `User` model and ViewSet, but I'm sticking to it for the sake of the example. In my model, I have larger JSON elements that I want to render, so I am doing some preprocessing in my `TableHTMLRenderer` to return JSON in indented form.

```
class TableHtmlRenderer(TemplateHTMLRenderer):
    media_type = "text/html"
    format = "api"
    template_name = "table_template.html"

    def get_template_context(self, data, renderer_context):
        for key in data.keys():
            try:
                data[key] = json.dumps(json.loads(data[key]), indent=4)
            except (JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
                pass

        context = {
            "data": data
        }

        response = renderer_context["response"]
        if response.exception:
            context["status_code"] = response.status_code

        return context
```

So controlled by the URL, I can switch between the default renderer and the Custom/Table renderer.

- localhost.me:8000/api/users/1/**?table**

[image: http://localhost.me:8000/api/users/1/?table]

- localhost.me:8000/api/users/1/

[image: http://localhost.me:8000/api/users/1/]

So far so good, I now have my own Renderer classes and I can modify how the API view for my User instance looks. I'm still struggling with the table, because line-breaks on long lines don't work and it won't stay inside of the div's boundaries.

Here is the `app.css` which is loaded in the `api.html` template.

```
pre.inline {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: contents;
}

table, th, td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;}

table {
    //table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100% !important;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

---

### Update 2

Since I can now display some views with a customized BrowsableAPIRenderer and templates with quite a few hacks, I came back to the problem that lead me to this question. I wanted to get to know how DRF renders my models, to make changes in order to display large nested dictionaries.

I found out that the `BrowsableAPIRenderer` inserts the model contents as a single string int he `api.html` template like this `{{ content|urlize_quoted_links }}` inside of `<pre>` tags.
The insertion takes place in the `BrowsableAPIRenderer.get_content` method.

```
# original code
renderer_context['indent'] = 4
content = renderer.render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

I now see that all I had to do is subclass `BrowsableAPIRenderer` and override the `get_content` method. I'm doing it like this.

```
class LogBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):    
    def get_content(self, renderer, data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context):
        """
        Extends BrowsableAPIRenderer.get_content.
        """
        if not renderer:
            return '[No renderers were found]'

        renderer_context['indent'] = 4
        # content = renderer.render(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)

        # try to convert all string-values into dictionaries
        data_dict = dict(data.items())
        for k in data_dict.keys():
            try:
                data_dict[k] = json.loads(data_dict[k], strict=False)
            except JSONDecodeError:
                # ignore errors and move on for now
                pass

        # dump into indented string again
        content = json.dumps(data_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True).encode(encoding="utf-8")

        render_style = getattr(renderer, 'render_style', 'text')
        assert render_style in ['text', 'binary'], 'Expected .render_style "text" or "binary", but got "%s"' % render_style
        if render_style == 'binary':
            return '[%d bytes of binary content]' % len(content)

        return content
```

I also realize that I could have worded my question differently to maybe come to this closure more quickly.

Comment: I did not quite get what you really want? Please, can you provide some example case for your scenario? What kind of table do you want?

Comment: So, django restframework's browsable API functionality makes it really easy to display my Django REST endpoints and also renders Database models as seen in the screenshot. You can customize most things in DRF, like changing the bootstrap theme or overwriting the templates that are used to build the pages. You can e.g. overwrite `api.html` to customize how the page I screenshot looks. I did not find a way to just customize how the model is represented and rendered. the kind of table doesn't really matter, if I can display the model in a table (e.g. key-value), I can display it in any way.

Comment: Actually I know the purpose of overriding templates and usage of BrowsableAPI, I just wanted to know your scenario, to give a better understandable answer. So, anyway I will now try to give an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most appropriate and best answer, but I think it is more or less what you want and it is a little hack.

Let's say we want to expose **/users/** endpoint and we have the following `views.py`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

UserModel = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

---

So, first, let's create `renderers.py` inside one of our apps (let's say we have `users` app):

```py
from rest_framework.renderers import BrowsableAPIRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer


class TableHtmlRenderer(TemplateHTMLRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/html'
    format = 'api'
    template_name = 'users/table_template.html'

    def get_template_context(self, data, renderer_context):
        context = {'data': data}
        response = renderer_context['response']
        if response.exception:
            context['status_code'] = response.status_code
        return context


class CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer(BrowsableAPIRenderer):

    def get_default_renderer(self, view):
        if view.detail:
            return TableHtmlRenderer()

        return super().get_default_renderer(view)
```

In this way we are overriding `BrowsableAPIRenderer` with our `CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer` just to change the default renderer for our `content` (In our case it is `dict` obj that is json serializable). We check whether our view is `detail=True` by accessing viewset.detail attribute.

Then, we need to override existing `TemplateHTMLRenderer` with our own `TableHTMLRenderer` to give our dict object as a `data` to a context of `users/table_template.html`

So, now we have to create our `users/table_template.html`:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Now, we are ready to check just after enabling our renderers in the `settings.py`:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'users.renderers.CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

If you see, now we replaced `rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer` with our own `users.renderers.CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer` custom renderer.

[image]

We see that now we have table instead of json structure.

I hope, this should work on your side too.

---

**UPDATE**

If we want to get rid of whitespace or we want more of a custom modification, we have to override and change the `api.html`. So, we create our own `users/api.html`:

```html
{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load rest_framework %}

{% block content %}
...
</span></pre>
            <div class="prettyprint">{{ content|urlize_quoted_links }}
            </div>
        </div>
...
{% endblock content %}
```

where `...` 3 dots are put, we have to copy and paste the rest of the `base.html` starting from `content` block because `content` block is too big and we want to change something that inside this block. We can not do it without copy-pasting the whole `content` block. If we compare our template with old `base.html`, the place where `</span>` element finishes, we remove `{{ content|urlize_quoted_links }}` context and put it inside a new div after the end of `</pre>` element as we see in the code example, so that now we do not use `<pre>` element and no extra whitespace is put.

Then, if we look at the result:
[image]

But, what is bad, now we have changed and overrode the whole template, so we broke other views too:
[image]

As a result, you see that our result became clumsy and we have made too much of hack to come to result that we want. That's why I would not really recommend overriding `api.html` just to change that `content` part. Instead, I would use my first answer which is less hacky, by overriding renderer classes.

Comment: This comes very close to what I imagined. Thanks for the detailed answer, it helped me understand the framework a bit more. It should be also possible to use the custom renderer only for a specific ViewSet instead of a global default, correct? I'll come back to this later today, when I had the chance to try it out. And by the way, which part of your answer would you consider hacky?

Comment: The `table_template` is rendered really weird, as seen in your screenshot, e.g. all whitespaces are rendered. Why is that? Where is the code that renders the data part (key, values from the example) in DRF? Is a similar template used?

Comment: @robinki actually, renderers are used in the global scope and it is not wise and recommended to use renderers for specific ViewSet. But with the hack that I have done in the `get_default_renderer` method of `CustomBrowsableAPIRenderer` you can check and use different content renderers. table_template is rendered weirdly because I did not override base.html that is inside rest_framework. If you look inside that template, you see that {{content}} already stays inside <pre> element which leaves all the whitespaces as it is written in the content. I will update my response and you will see.

Comment: I used your suggestion with the `<pre>` tags. I did some more changes to only use the renderer for my specific view. I **updated the question** describing what I changed.

Comment: @robinki I see that you understood renderers better and your solution looks pretty acceptable. Regarding your question about line-breaks, sorry to say that, but can't help with front-side problems as I am more concerned about back-end problems. Hope you will find an answer to your problem :)